# How to escape string while programmatically generating markdown table

Tags: c#, markdown

I use C# to programmatically generate markdown tables from user input.

**Edit**

Consider this demo code:

```
var a = Console.ReadLine();
var b = Console.ReadLine();
var c = Console.ReadLine();

var markdownTableBuilder = new StringBuilder();
markdownTableBuilder.AppendLine("| Column A | Column B | Column C |");
markdownTableBuilder.AppendLine("| -------- | -------- | ---------|");

markdownTableBuilder.AppendLine($"| {a} | {b} | {c}");
markdownTableBuilder.AppendLine("");

Console.WriteLine(markdownTableBuilder.ToString());
```

I want to escape all markdown syntax from a,b,c variables. For example, if user enters something like **Hello | *world***, it should be escaped to **Hello \| \*world\***

Comment: Not entirely sure  what you mean, but could you effectively write something like:
`foreach(Char char in string){bool escaped = false; string noMarkDown = ""; if (char == '<'){escaped = true;} if (char=='>'){escaped = false;} if (!escaped){string+=char;}}`

Comment: If that's what you mean say so and I'll write it up as an answer

Comment: @JamesHughes sorry, but I don't want to remove characters. I want to "escape" them. See my edit.

Comment: Oh right, well what you could do then is convert the string to a List<char> iterate through it, and `if (charList[i+1]==listMarkdown.contains(i+1)` add the escape character

Comment: @JamesHughes yeah, that could work but I think grek40 solution is much simpler. Nevertheless, thanks for your input!

Comment: I just looked at his and it's definitely better, but I have no fecking clue how to use Regex, good luck!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use regex for replacement:

```
string escaped = Regex.Replace(userInput, @"([|\\*])", @"\$1");
```

This will find any `'|', '\', '*'` character and put a `'\'` in front of it.

Comment: it will not replace the \ character, because the backslash character \ here means escaping the `*` character. We need double backslash \ here. 
The correct code is 
`string escaped = Regex.Replace(userInput, @"([|\\*])", @"\$1");`

Comment: `Regex.Replace(userInput, $"([{Regex.Escape(@"|\*")}])", @"\$1")`